# How to post vector to a HTTP endpoint

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have the following data type that is populated in C++

```
std::vector<uint8_t> bytes;
```

Using libcurl, how do I post this to an HTTP endpoint ?

Tried the following code, but I think it won't work with my post data

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://1.2.3.4:9002/multicastdataclient-message");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, &bytes);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  if(res != CURLE_OK)
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Comment: Which of curl samples did you try?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Updated the sample code in my post ! Thanks for replying !

Comment: `bytes.data()` or `&bytes[0]` are possibly what you're looking for rather than `&bytes`. It appears you also need to set the size of the data, and depending on content you may need to encode it. https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html

Comment: In addition to @RetiredNinja suggestion read https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html - you have to set the size of the data to send using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE option

Comment: Read CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS dicumentation *carefully*. There are at least two issues you want to take care of, null-termination and content-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all the comments, the following code worked !

CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://1.2.3.4:9002/message");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, bytes.size());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, bytes.data());

  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  if(res != CURLE_OK)
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
  curl_easy_strerror(res));
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
else
{
  DBG("curl empty !!");
}
```